# My date format scramble between italian to english VBA word excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba

I did a macro to extract a date from a word document, and put in excel.
I have a date picker content control in word.
My locale in my PC is set to italian DD/MM/YYYY, my date picker word locale is set to Italian DD/MM/YYYY. on my date picker I see the date as e.g. 08/06/2017.
Now I use:

```
Activeworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = objwdDoc.ContentControls(12).Range.Text
```

but i get 06/08/2017
I tried:

```
Activeworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = format(objwdDoc.ContentControls(12).Range.Text, "DD/MM/YYYY")
```

But i get the date like 06/08/2017

if I use:

```
Activeworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = format(objwdDoc.ContentControls(12).Range.Text, "MM/DD/YYYY")
```

I actually get the right date

I check the vba code using a variable like:

```
date1 = format(objwdDoc.ContentControls(12).Range.Text, "MM/DD/YYYY")

    Activeworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = date1
```

and in debug my date1 variable is correct: 08/06/2017

When I check in excel A1 tho, I get 06/08/2017 and that cell is formatted like "short date, dd/MM/YYYY")

why?

Comment: I wonder if you need to format that cell as `text` or similar to avoid Excel trying to be `clever`

Comment: It might be a bit more complicated, but it is better to convert any date string first into a date variable and to set the value of a cell with the value of the variable. This makes code-wise sure, that you set the correct value. If your worksheet would still show the wrong date, you can start debugging by explicitly setting the cells numberformat to "default date" manually and code-wise. In the end the glitch should reveal itself.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I get around the issue with dates (irish date format is the same as Italian). This is due to the fact that American format is MM/DD/YYYYY and sometimes when it can be either it goes back to basics.
To prevent it happening I do the following (where I can)

1. To prevent the excel sheet corrupting the format I convert it on read to yyyyMMdd and save as integer.
2. To enforce the correct look when writing back to excel I use the german format, which people can read and understand but excel doesn't recognise on non german setup as a date, i.e. DD.MM.YYYY

It is not so much of a solution as a work around.